# Spring getBean on NamedParameterJdbcTemplate takes a long time

Tags: spring, named-parameters

I am facing a weird scenario with the Spring `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. I have a project setup with `context.getBean()`calling for a Spring `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. This is being called as part of initial setup through the `@PostConstruct` method. Essentially, the post construct method makes a call to the database to get a few environment related setup to be done.

Now, the `getBean` call to the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` bean takes a long time -- in fact under Eclipse I've had to wait for more than 5 minutes and never got an instance. However, the same code works perfectly fine if I use a `@Inject` instead of `getBean`.

Secondly, the same setup also has a bean for plain `JdbcTemplate`. If I get this bean and then call the bean with `NamedParamJdbcTemplate`, then there is no issue. The problem seems to be only when the `NamedParamJdbcTemplate` is the first bean call.

Is there a difference in this being called  first vs second time? Aren't we supposed to call this as the first bean? I am unable to find any documentation with regards to this.

Thanks,
Aravind

Comment: Generally when you are doing things like `getBean` you are doing things wrong. Instead you should be using `@Autowired` or (as you did `@Inject`) instead. Also generally speaking there shouldn't be a difference in how you get the bean. However without seeing some actual code it will be a guessing game, so please add some code.